# Can't disable autoplay after calling .load

Tags: flowplayer

I have a page full of video links that when clicked, opens up a modal window with flowplayer inside it.  I load the video into the modal by calling the .load function but I can't stop the video from autoplaying.

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="flowplayer">
        <video preload="none">
            <!-- these are just dummy videos that will be replaced by the .load function -->
            <source type="video/mp4" src="/Assets/video/dummy.mp4">
            <source type="video/webm" src="/Assets/video/dummy.webm">
        </video>
    </div> 
</div>

//script, called when user clicks a video link
var api = flowplayer();
api.load([
    { mp4: //path to video clicked, stored in data- in div },
    { webm: //path to video clicked, stored in data- in div }
]);
```

Videos load and play fine, I just can't figure out how to stop the autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to display a [splash screen](http://flowplayer.org/docs/#splash), when the modal is displayed.  Only when the user clicks on the splash screen do you then need to load the video.

You could bind to the load event and update the source(s) there.

```
api.bind("load", function(e, api) {

   // do your thing

});
```

[flowplayer events](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html#events)

Comment: So I added is-splash to my flowplayer container tried the api.bind call but now it just says html5: video not found.